# GIT Tag step- cancelled in the build

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have been observing that the git tag step failing since a few days with the below error.

Could you please let me know if there is already a fixed.

*##[warning]An image label with the label Ubuntu16 does not exist.
,##[error]The remote provider was unable to process the request.
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: Ubuntu16*

Job preparation parameters

https://dev.azure.com/chevron/GUS-MCBU-ChemicalLookBackTool/_build?definitionId=34682

Thanks
Seetha

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 image was removed on September 20, 2021.
Oddly, at the time of this post, if you don't specify the image version, then Azure DevOps will try to use the Ubuntu 16.04 image that has already been removed.
To solve this issue, you need to specify in your pipeline that you want to use the latest Ubuntu image.

For Yaml pipelines:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```

You can read more about this topic on this MS developer community [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pipelines-without-a-pool-specified-are-f/1557841)

Answer (score 0):

So I have been getting this error recently as well! If you look at the [microsoft hosted build agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you'll notice that Ubuntu16 is not supported anymore. The docs were changed [very recently](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/commit/a04d7ee0904e69429681460c89ecbed9f6815c4d).

This is only happening for me on builds that are triggered by commits-- manually triggering a build from the pipeline UI works just fine, and the build will show  the image as "ubuntu:latest" instead. I don't have a solution, just a work around, but I suspect that the service connection that the commit trigger uses to get the pipeline is caching some sort of value that it shouldn't be.

Update: I was able to solve this by going into the *pipeline's* settings via the Classic Pipeline editor and adjusting the default hosted agent type from `Ubuntu16` to latest.

For a YAML pipeline, the way that I got to the classic editor was by
a) revoking the token that my source repo granted to the azure service connection (in my case I revoked the [token in Bitbucket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/connect))
b) go to the azure pipeline and try to kick off a new run
c) get an error that the authorization is denied, and a link to the classic editor for the pipeline.
d) create a new service connection for the source repo
e) adjust the default agent

see screenshot for view of the classic editor:
[image: screenshot of the azure devops classic pipeline editor]
If you click on the "Pipeline" step above the "Get Sources" task, you can adjust the default agent.